# SharePoint Online Powershell Folder creation

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I need to be able to script folder creation from a csv into a SharePoint Online document library with each folder with permission inheritance disabled and for different user to each folder to be added.

The following code can create the folders and disable the inheritance but it seems to try add a group but not a user. How to make it add a user instead?

Thanks.

```bsh
### Get the user credentials
$credential = Get-Credential
$username = $credential.UserName
$password = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force

### Input Parameters
$url = 'URL HERE'
$csvfilepath='C:\Scripts\data.csv'
$libname ='BUS61'

### References
# Specified the paths where the dll's are located.
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Scripts\SPOCmdlets\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Scripts\SPOCmdlets\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'


### CreateFolder with Permissions Function
function CreateFolderWithPermissions()
{

    # Connect to SharePoint Online and get ClientContext object.
    $clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)
    $credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword)
    $clientContext.Credentials = $credentials

    Function GetRole
    {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param
        (
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
            [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleType]$rType
        )

        $web = $clientContext.Web
        if ($web -ne $null)
        {
            $roleDefs = $web.RoleDefinitions
            $clientContext.Load($roleDefs)
            $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
            $roleDef = $roleDefs | Where-Object { $_.RoleTypeKind -eq $rType }
            return $roleDef
        }
        return $null
    }

    # Get the SharePoint web
    $web = $clientContext.Web;
    $clientContext.Load($web)

    #Get the groups
    $groups = $web.SiteGroups
    $clientContext.Load($groups)
    $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()


    #Read CSV File and iterate
    $csv = Import-CSV $csvfilepath
    foreach ($row in $csv)
    {
        #Create Folder
        $folder = $web.Folders.Add($libname + "/" + $row.Folder)
        $clientContext.Load($folder)
        $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

        #Assign Role
        $group = $groups.GetByName($row.Group)
        $clientContext.Load($group)
        $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

        $roleType= $row.Role
        $roleTypeObject = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleType]$roleType
        $roleObj = GetRole $roleTypeObject
        $usrRDBC = $null
        $usrRDBC = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection($clientContext)
        $usrRDBC.Add($roleObj)

        # Remove inherited permissions
        $folder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance($false, $true)
        $clientContext.Load($folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add($group, $usrRDBC))
        $folder.Update()
        $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()           

        # Display the folder name and permission
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Blue 'Folder Name: ' $folder.Name ' Group: '$row.Group ' Role: ' $roleType;

    }
}
#Execute the function
CreateFolderWithPermissions
```

Comment: did you chcked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you will define user login in your CSv file. Than you have to change the line:

```
$group = $groups.GetByName($row.Group)
```

to

```
$user = $web.EnsureUser($row.User)
```

and replace all references to `$group` variable with `$user`

More generic approach for searching for a user (with for example display name) would be using `Utility.ResolvePrincipal` method:

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.Utility]::ResolvePrincipal($clientContext, $web, "DisplayName", ([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.PrincipalType]::User), ([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.PrincipalSource]::All), $null, $false)
```